# Why is my cursor not showing in Mobile VR? (1.0.4)

Tags: aframe

I noticed the 360 Image Gallery example on the Aframe.io website is broken so I have been trying to fix it.

I've got it to work on Desktop and 2D mobile browser, but when I switch to VR mode in my mobile (iPhone) browser, there is no cursor and I can't change scenes anymore.

What am I missing?

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/bubble-glitter-specialist

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something change in Safari iOS 13.4.1 that broke VR mode. More info at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4554